# magnetic absolut shaft encoder calibration

Tags: arduino, magnetometer

I have an absolute magnetic shaft encoder. I want to use it in order get the azimuth angle of that a motor. I want get values from the encoder but I want to know it is aligned to the magnetic north or it is irrelevant?

So if the 0 angle at the shaft encoder I have to do a manual calibration with a magnetometer and add or subtract my magnetic declination.

I am going to use a magnetometer to check it but I was wondering if there is a standard answer for all these devices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about machine calibration, not computer programming.

Answer (score 2):

The magnet inside the encoder is surely much stronger than earth's magnetic field.  The motor you connect to the encoder will be generating a magnetic field.  Interference from earth is not the first of your concerns.

You don't need a magnetometer to convince yourself of this, just pick up the entire encoder, rotate it, and see if the reading changes.